# Python Regular Expression to match specific sequence of characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

I am a very basic user of regular expressions in Python and need some expert advise to 
solve a problem with the use of regular expressions.

I am trying to extract some information from a string with following set of rules.

1. Starts with a **$(**
2. After starting tag must have a word.
3. *Optionally*, following word it may contain

   - any characters except **'** and **"** [*if used singly not in pairs*] till the end character **)**
   - **'** and **"** [*if used singly not in pairs*] are allowed only if escaped using a **\**
   - may even allow **)** if enclosed within **''** or **""**.
4. End with a **)**

As a solution, It would be easy if somehow it is allowed to define and use a special type of character inside character set [].

For example:

```
re.compile("""\$\((\w*)
              [(any characters except ' and " [if used singly not in pairs] )
               (' and " [if used singly not in pairs] are allowed only if escaped using a \)
               ( even ) if enclosed within '' or "")
              ]\)""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Some tests:

- this $(listInput) tail              -> listInput
- this $(listInput:DS) tail           -> listInput:DS
- this $(listInput:J=") ":S=.o) tail  -> listInput:J=") ":S=.o
- this $(listInput:J=join\'with) tail -> listInput:J=join'with

Is it possible to do something like this in Python, or my approach towards the solution is not Pythonic ?
Also suggest, if there could be any better solutions.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to do what you ask:

```
^\$\((\w(?:\w|[^)\\"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\\"|\\')*)\)
```

Break-down:

```
^                   # start of string
\$\(                # "$("
(                   # start group 1
  \w                  # a word character
  (?:                 # start non-capturing group, one of:
    \w                  # a word character
    |                   # or
    [^)\\"']            # anything except ")" and special characters
    |                   # or
    "[^"]*"             # a double-quoted section
    |                   # or
    '[^']*'             # a single-quoted section
    |                   # or
    \\"                 # a backslash-escaped double quote
    |                   # or 
    \\'                 # a backslash-escaped single quote
  )*                  # end group, repeat
)                   # end group 1
\)                  # ")"
```

It matches like your examples require.

Shortcomings:

- In the absence of a better specification of "word", I used `\w`. Familiarize yourself with what `\w` matches and use something more specific, if necessary.
- No quote nesting allowed. (that's something Python regexes can't do)
- It runs over closing quotes in quoted sections. More info is required to get this right.
- No escaped quotes in a quoted section (though that would be possible to add)

Test:

```
regex = re.compile("^\$\((\w(?:\w|[^)\\\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|\\\"|\\')*)\)")
string = "$(listInput:J=join\'with) tail"

r = regex.search(string)

r.groups()
# -> (u"listInput:J=join\\'with",)

regex.findall(string)
# -> [u"listInput:J=join\\'with"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak, your solution helped me perfectly as I was expecting.